# How to add Jasypt library to OS X?

Tags: java, macos

I just came across JASYPT library and I wanted to try it out. I have googled a fair bit but failed to find a guide to add new Java libraries. I have OS X 10.7, which directory do I unpack the Jasypt library into?

Jasypt: http://www.jasypt.org/

EDIT: I use Eclipse for Java Dev, I just created a new project and want to integrate this library into it.

Comment: Do you use an IDE? Do you need it for an existing project or want to include it into an existing program? Please give some more Informations what you want to do.

Comment: @ollo I use Eclipse, I am still new to it.

Comment: Just insert Jasypt jar to your project classpath.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Eclipse it is: *Properties > Java Build Path > Libraries.* (Contextmenu of your project)

There you add **jasypt-1.9.0.jar**

if you use Java 5 or older you also have to include **icu4j-3.4.4.jar**

*(Versions may differ from yours)*

Answer (score 1):

You can change your build path following these steps:

- Right click in your project node;
- Properties;
- Java Build Path;
- Libraries;
- Add JARs or Add External JARs;
- Add the jar(s) of Jasypt;
- Apply your changes;
- Test it.